# Fingerprint byte array to Imagesource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fingerprint, imagesource

I am trying to convert fingerprint byte array to imagesource in the WPF application but my tricks not working.
Here is the code :

```
  byte[] fp_image;  //fp_image contains the fingerprint byte array result 

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fp_image))
  {
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
      FpImage.Source = ConvertToImageSource(bmp);
  }
  public static ImageSource ConvertToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
  {
     var imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
         var snapshotBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
         return (ImageSource)imageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(snapshotBytes); ;
     }
  }
```

Note : If I convert any other image to byte array and convert it back to image with this code it's working.

Comment: `byte[] fp_image` contains required image headers? for example you are trying to save to png but It has png file header?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü no , it doesn't contain any headers. If it should contain , How can I assign image header to byte[] fp_image

Comment: All that code with the Winforms System.Drawing.Bitmap doesn't make sense. If `fp_image` contains a valid bitmap frame (encoded as e.g. PNG or JPEG), you could directly pass it to a MemoryStream constructor, and assign that stream to the `StreamSource` property of a WPF BitmapImage. If `fp_image` is a raw pixel buffer, you need to know the pixel format, width and height of the bitmap, and pass those values to one of the `BitmapSource.Create()` overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `byte[] fp_image` contains raw data then you could directly create a `BitmapSource` (which is a subclass of `ImageSource`) with the method shown below. However, you need to know the width, height and pixel format of the bitmap in your buffer.

```
public BitmapSource GetBitmapFromRawBytes(
    byte[] rawBytes, int width, int height, PixelFormat format)
{
    var stride = (width * format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    return BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, format, null, rawBytes, stride);
}
```

Comment: `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` is nonsense. Pass `rawBytes`directly to `BitmapSource.Create()` to create a **WPF** BitmapSource. And did OP tell anything about whether they know width, height and pixel format?

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand why it is nonsense. I provided a working solution. I do not see how I can use your solution.

Comment: I have edited your answer so that your example creates a WPF BitmapSource, not a WinForms Bitmap. Your solution also assumes a fixed pixel format. This should instead also be passed as a parameter, just like width and height. The stride however can be calculated.

Comment: All this still requires that OP *knows* width, height and format, what we don't know.

Comment: Please, keep it readable. This is C#, we write opening curly braces on a new line.

Comment: Braces on a new line is the rule of C#? I always assumed it was preference

Comment: It is a very widely accepted convention, just like the other way is for Java.